# Is there an R function or package for finding the gradient and Hessian of a vectorized equation?

Tags: r, vectorization, gradient, hessian

For example if I want to find the gradient and Hessian with respect to x of:

```
f = function(x,y,alpha,A,b){
  return((1/n)*(y-alpha*x)%*%(y-alpha*x) + (A%*%x-b)%*%(A%*%x-b))
}
```

Comment: is A a matrix? if so should you not have transpose somewhere in your equation?

Comment: possibly the `madness` package?

Comment: I think %*% doesn't care if you transpose or not it will always do the inner product. Thank you I will look at the madness package.

Comment: I believe @Onyambu is right, I am unable to correctly call your function. My answer below computes *something*, even if it's meaningless.

Comment: numeric or symbolic? If you want numeric, use the **numDeriv** package.

Comment: It will only do inner product if the two are vectors. but in your case, you have A capitalized. so i thought it was a matrix.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right one of them needs to be transposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRAN package [Deriv](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Deriv) can compute symbolic derivatives of R functions.
In the code below I have removed the call to `return` in the posted function `f`.
Function `DDeriv` is a copy&paste from [this RPubs post](https://rpubs.com/venkatritch/333327) changed to use `Deriv` instead of base `D` that does not accept functions as its first argument.

```
library(Deriv)

DDeriv <- function(expr, name, order = 1){
  if(order < 1) stop("Order must be >= 1")
  if(order == 1) Deriv(expr, name)
  else DDeriv(Deriv(expr, name), name, order - 1)
}


f <- function(x,y,alpha,A,b){
  (1/n)*(y-alpha*x)%*%(y-alpha*x) + (A%*%x-b)%*%(A%*%x-b)
}
```

Using function `Deriv` directly:

```
Deriv(f, "x")
#function (x, y, alpha, A, b) 
#{
#    .e1 <- -alpha
#    .e3 <- A %*% x - b
#    .e5 <- y - alpha * x
#    (.e1 %*% .e5 + .e5 %*% .e1)/n + .e3 %*% A + A %*% .e3
#}
```

Using function `DDeriv`:

```
DDeriv(f, "x", 1)
#function (x, y, alpha, A, b) 
#{
#    .e1 <- -alpha
#    .e3 <- A %*% x - b
#    .e5 <- y - alpha * x
#    (.e1 %*% .e5 + .e5 %*% .e1)/n + .e3 %*% A + A %*% .e3
#}

DDeriv(f, "x", 2)
#function (x, y, alpha, A, b) 
#{
#    .e1 <- -alpha
#    2 * (.e1 %*% .e1/n) + 2 * A %*% A
#}
```